# android create text file on install

Tags: java, android

I need help storing data on my Android app.  I need to create a text file, but only once.  I have tried if(file.exists()) and if (file!=null) but nothing's working.I need this text file to store user data strings between app restarts.  This code will create the file onCreate everytime, but I need it to only do it if the file doesnt already exist

`private void createFile(String filename){
        if(memoryFile != null){
        memoryFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code will create the file onCreate everytime

No, it will not. It will not create any file. It creates an instance of a `File` object. That is a Java object that represents a (possible) file on the filesystem. It does not actually create the file. To create the file, write something to it, using a `FileOutputStream` (and a background thread). To see if the file already exists, call `exists()` on `memoryFile`.

Also, note that you do not need `getApplicationContext()` here. Just use `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: thanks! could you possible link me to something about the background thread?

Comment: @kevinb: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads